# Is it possible to assign multiple ORM configurations to a Java Model?

Tags: java, android, orm, ormlite

We have this situation:
One backend written with Spring.
One native Android app.

They share many of the models.

What it has been done is writing models in a package on the backend and then export it as jar in android.

On android we are using OrmLite to interact with these models on the DB. The models have their proper annotations to achieve this. On the backend we basically write raw crud queries for each model, this is getting crazy as every time we add a field we need to update all the relevant queries.

What we would like to achieve is to use another orm on the server. The problem is that server and tablet for old bad design choices have different column and table names even though the models are the same. Renaming columns and tables cannot be done because it involves too much work.

We need to get things smarter, but we would also like to avoid duplicating the models just to remap the models to a different database schema.

Do you have any idea on a smart way on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, "Renaming columns and tables cannot be done because it involves too much work" is the best solution to have consistent and managebale code base in the long term.

For the short term, what could be smart is to use XML based configuration on the server and stick to annotations for the tablet app.

**Update**

You want to look at [JPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) specification, it defines the persistence mechanism in java. There are multiple implementation providers for it, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API#JPA_2.2) is the list for providers of the specificaions latest version.

I only have experience with [Hibernate ORM](https://hibernate.org/orm/) which along with its native API also provides implementation for JPA. It has XML based configuration option in addition to annotations. You will have evaluate which provider suits your requirment.

If the annotation of ORMlite differ from JPA then you can even use the JPA annotation in the entity classes besides the ORMLite annotation. But beware this will make your entity model classes messy and you will need both your selected JPA implemantion library and ORMLite library on the classpath of entity model.

Comment: I know that, but we already evaluated that, its not doable for various reasons.  One of these is that tablet keeps reference of server Pks but has also their own pks as it can create entities on its own. But the server does not store device pks as it does not need them. So we should migrate everything to UUIDs but this is a pain as it touches a vast part of the codebase on both backend and app sides.

So when you say XML based configuration do you have a specific ORM in your mind?